# ChunkReadFilterService not working properly in php/laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, import, chunks

i am trying to import an excel file in my database, Laravel/mysql. I am using php spreadsheet library and trying to do my task with chunks because excel files can be too large.
Problem is that, chunks are not working properly, i want chunks of 300 lines, but it picks first chunk and then add new chunk in previous, and ultimately gives the incorrent chunk results in lot of duplicates and garbage data in my database.
here is my code.

```
$totalRows=1051;
$currentRows=1;
    while($currentRows <= $totalRows){
                    
                $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
                $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

                $chunkFilter = new ChunkReadFilterService();
                $reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
                $chunkFilter->setRows($currentRows,300);
              
                $spreadsheet = $reader->load($path);
                
                $sheetData = [];
               
                $sheetData   = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, 
                     true);
                  $currentRows += 300;
                
                echo count($sheetData);
                echo '</br>';
               
                
               
                
               
                
            }
```

it gives the result

```
    300
600
900
1051
```

while, it should echo 300 every time, because chunkSize is 300 and it should pick the 300 records every time, only last time should be 151.
Any help or suggenstion would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try ChunkReadFilter

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#combining-read-filters-with-the-setsheetindex-method-to-split-a-large-csv-file-across-multiple-worksheets

example:

```
$inputFileType = 'Csv';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example2.csv';

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

/**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
$chunkSize = 65530;
/**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
$chunkFilter = new ChunkReadFilter();

/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/
/**    and that we want to store it in contiguous rows/columns  **/

$reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter)
    ->setContiguous(true);

/**  Instantiate a new Spreadsheet object manually  **/
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

/**  Set a sheet index  **/
$sheet = 0;
/**  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/
/**  $startRow is set to 2 initially because we always read the headings in row #1  **/
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 1000000; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
    /**  Tell the Read Filter which rows we want to read this loop  **/
    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);

    /**  Increment the worksheet index pointer for the Reader  **/
    $reader->setSheetIndex($sheet);
    /**  Load only the rows that match our filter into a new worksheet  **/
    $reader->loadIntoExisting($inputFileName,$spreadsheet);
    /**  Set the worksheet title for the sheet that we've justloaded)  **/
    /**    and increment the sheet index as well  **/
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Country Data #'.(++$sheet));
}
```